# Macos M1 low-level port i/o

Tags: macos, clang, apple-m1, pci

I have a student task to read PCI info via 0xCF8 and 0xCFC ports using outl(), inl() functions. It assumes I use Linux x86, but can I do such things on macos with M1 chip?
I found <sys/uio.h> header but it does not define functions prototypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outl` and `inl` are platform-specific functions for Linux.  If it is an exercise, and you have to submit a code snippet, then I suggest installing some kind of virtual machine (VirtualBox or maybe Docker Desktop) and write a program for Linux, otherwise your code would be unlikely to be accepted, since it'd use completely different low-level API.